# Google maps component in Angular not receiving injected service

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack, mean

I've tried it all at this point.
I have a (data) service that provides data to 2 different components on the same page. This service provides data in the from of a promise. Of the 2 components, one is a google maps component. Also the data comes from an API I made which runs on a different port. The data is successfully sent to the other component (which implements OnInit) but not the google maps component (implements AfterViewInit). The example code for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Drink} from './drink/drink.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrinkDataService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  
  private apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
  
  public getDrinks() : Promise<Drinks[]>{
    const url: string = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/drinks`
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as Drink[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  
  private handleError(error: any) : Promise<any> {
    console.log('Something has gone wrong', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I discovered that the data is only accessible from the view (HTML of the component) for some reason, so the service is working fine. The solution was to explicitly make the get function local to the component return a value instead of void.